# .AmqpResourceNotAvailableException: The channelMax limit is reached. Try later

Tags: java, spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

I face an issue when trying to send some messages over rabbitmq protocol: The channelMax limit is reached. Try later.
I'm using Spring boot rabbitmq libs and more precisely default rabbitTemplate convertAndSend method.
I have to handle a lot of data in my program and need to send it over amqp.

My question is: Is rabbitTemplate creating a channel on each convertSend ?
And is the channel closed after convertAndSend ?

Comment: The channels are cached and reused by the `CachingConnectionFactory; you should only have a few channels because publishing is very fast. What version of Boot/spring-rabbit are you using?

Comment: Hi in my pom i have spring-boot-starter-amqp 2.1.6 release

Comment: 2.1.6 is very old; the latest 2.1.x release is 2.1.18; I don't see any changes since then in this area, but you should upgrade. Perhaps your broker channelMax is very small? You can get channel cache statistics by calling `getCacheProperties()` on the connection factory. It is also available over JMX.